# Laravel relations/subscription handling

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I'm relatively new to Laravel and trying to create a subscription checker. Please do not suggest cashier as the payments will be using alternative methods such as bitcoin.

I have two models the User model and the Subscription model.

In the user model I have the method subscription that returns the relationship that the user has one subscription.

```
public function subscription()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Subscription::Class);
}
```

In the subscription model I have a User method that returns the relationship that the subscription belongs to a user

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::Class);
}
```

I'm now wanting to return a status in my blade template whether the current date is past the enddate date in the subscription table. I've created a isSubscribed method in the subscription model to return whether the current date is past the enddate.

```
public function isSubscribed()
{
  $now = Carbon::now();

  if ($now->gt($this->enddate))
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

In the blade template I'm showing data based on whether the user subscription method returns true or false

```
            @if(Auth::user()->subscription->isSubscribed())
              You're subscribed
            @else
              You're not subscribed
            @endif
```

The issue I now have is that if a record doesn't exist for the user in the subscription its throwing an error of

Call to a member function isSubscribed() on null

Is there a way to return false if no records exist for the user in the subscription model or am I doing this entirely the wrong way?

Apologies if this an incredible simple answer but I've scoured the docs and cant seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a collection is empty

So `Auth::user()->subscription->isEmpty()`

will return true if there are no subscriptions for the current user.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-isempty

Comment: That doesn't work either it just throws the below error

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty()`

And if I do

`Auth::user()->subscription->isEmpty()`

It throws a null error again

Comment: On which page are you showing this ?, i am assuming that you need to be logged in when viewing that, Because if you can view that page as a guest that obviously won't work

Comment: It's under the Auth middleware so you need to be logged in to view it. If I have a record in the Subscription table for the user it doesnt throw an error it will only throw an error if a subscription isnt in the table.